# Questions about values in API Meria, format JSON

Tags: json, excel, rest

I have a Meria API who allow me to see information like this (this is the example given by Meria, this is not mine, actually):

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "currencyCode": "KAVA",
        "amount": 75,
        "reward": 0.01027898,
        "lockedReward": 0,
        "startDate": 1590582716,
        "variations": [
            {
                "amount": 75,
                "date": 1590582716,
                "effectiveDate": 1590669116,
                "applied": 1
            }
        ],
        "credits": [
            {
                "amount": 0.00432936,
                "date": 1590710400,
                "releaseDate": false,
                "released": 1
            },
            {
                "amount": 0.00594962,
                "date": 1590624000,
                "releaseDate": false,
                "released": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I have some questions about this:

1. What does the `"lockedReward"` represent in the general information?
2. My guess is, in the `"variations"` section, `"date"` represent the starting date, and `"effectiveDate"` represent the actual date (at least the date from API call), am I right?
3. What does `"releaseDate"` represent in the `"credits"` section?
4. In the same way, what does the boolean `"released"` represent?
5. Finally, I'm trying to synthetize everything in a Excel file, but I don't know how to convert this date format to a string one, any advice?

I tried to subtract the date and the release date to see the difference, so I understood that those numbers are minutes, which I can divide by 1440 (60*24) and it gave me a pretty good number of days (I don't remember exactly the date I stacked my cryptos, explaining the "pretty good"). But the problem remains: how can I convert them into dates? Do I HAVE to indicate the starting date and then add my days in Excel? Sounds a bit complicated, is there another solution?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This question should probably be directed to their support team (after checking their docs)